# Visualforce version affecting picklist values

Tags: visualforce, picklist

I have a pick list and the default values are not same when I changed between a very old version land the latest version. How is version related to what's displayed in pick list.  All other settings are same except for version. Anyone faced similar issue? Will appreciate any info, links or blog posts on this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Starting with Spring '17, Salesforce introduced a new ["ApiName" feature](https://developer.salesforce.com/blogs/developer-relations/2017/01/keeping-picklist-integrations-safe-using-api-names.html). This means that even if the labels changed, you could leave the values alone and not break integrations. If your code doesn't distinguish between the value and the label, this is why you'd have a discrepancy between values.